# How to create a list of draggable custom markers for google maps

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Well it's been some time since I've visited the very helpful world of StackOverflow, but I'm back again with another question to help me try to do more than I'm currently capable.

I'd like to put a google map on one of my sites, and I'd like it to have a list of custom markers on one side of the map that a visitor to the site can drag onto the map to identify various features - lets say the list has custom markers for a shop, house and office for example. The visitor drags the appropriate marker to the map at the position of where the feature is. They might want to drag multiple copies of the same custom marker (e.g many shops), so the marker must re-appear in the list after the user drags it to the map. When the user drops the marker, they should get presented with an info box that asks the user for some more information and then prompts them to save that marker so that when anyone else visits they can see the feature too (but not change it). I really want to make it so that when the user saves the marker it adds all the info to a mysql database and also emails me the details from the infobox including the lat-long of the marker.

So that's the end goal and I know it's a BIG task, but if anyone can point me in the direction of something as a starter for ten I'd be really grateful.

Many thanks,

Rob.

Comment: look at [that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#MarkerAnimations) example and if you have a specific code problem then come back and post some code

Comment: See [this thread in the google maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/adec0050cd340390/fef0e8df166f08db?lnk=gst&q=drag+marker+onto+map#fef0e8df166f08db), it has a link to [this example (which looks like exactly what you are asking for)](http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/drag-from-outside.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions - You're right that is the start of exactly what I was looking for. Incidentally, I have also found another site that does EXACTLY what I was trying to achieve - https://www.streetviolence.org Now all I need to do is get them to show me how they did it :-D

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample example with custom draggable markers.

More specifically it contains the following marker types:

- Parking
- Info
- Library

The pointsOfInterest array contains the markers which are shown when the Add Some Markers link is pressed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // points of interest
            var pointsOfInterest = [
                    ['Chicago Parking', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 'parking'],
                    ['Illinois Library', 40.797177, -89.406738, 'library'],
                    ['Detroit Info', 42.302284,-83.231215, 'info']
                ],
                // map initial center position
                demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -87),
                map;

            // initialize the map
            function initialize() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    zoom: 7,
                    center: demoCenter,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
            }

            // some standard icons for google markers
            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var icons = {
                parking: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png',
                    shadow: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.shadow.png'
                },
                library: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png',
                    shadow: iconBase + 'library_maps.shadow.png'
                },
                info: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png',
                    shadow: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.shadow.png'
                }
            };

            // create draggable marker and add in map
            function createMarker(feature) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                    shadow: {
                        url: icons[feature.type].shadow,
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 34)
                    },
                    draggable: true,
                    map: map
                });
                return marker;
            }

            // add the markers included inside the pointsOfInterest array
            function addMarkers() {
                var marker,
                i,
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (i = 0; i < pointsOfInterest.length; i++) {

                    var feature = new Object();
                    // set type
                    feature.type = pointsOfInterest[i][3];
                    // set position
                    feature.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pointsOfInterest[i][1], pointsOfInterest[i][2]);
                    // create the marker
                    var marker = createMarker(feature);

                    // add a listener to do something on marker click
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent(pointsOfInterest[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="basic-map">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
            <a href="#" class="add-markers">Add Some Markers</a>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your sample example, that's really useful.  Incidentally, I have also found a website that does EXACTLY what I was trying to achieve (different purpose but same concept) - https://www.streetviolence.org Now all I need to do is get them to show me how they did it :-D